# Is there a way to return duplicate values as blanks in a column using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, shopify

For some background on the issue:

I'm currently in the process of performing a data integration from a bespoke PHP eCommerce site to Shopify using MySQL, as a result, I must transform the product data to import it into Shopify. I was given a database of the old website as my source of data.

Currently, the data is set out like this:

[image: Original Table]

[image: Expected Table]

Is there anyway to return these duplicate values as blanks/nulls?

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated, first post here so apologies if there's some issues. Thanks!

Comment: This type of transformation is better done in the presentation layer.

Comment: I'm seconding what Gordon said, but have to add that this kind of transformation seems like a really odd thing to need for a data migration. "Blanking" that information would make it **harder** to import.

Answer (score -1):

You are in for a whole can of whoop here. So the recipe I would script up is pretty simple, with an amazing amount of holy crap am I ever in for it here and I am now making $2/hr because I took on this crappy job....

- Craft a script to read the old system and extract the values for a single product.

  - write a translation to go from old product schema to the Shopify schema. This is where you will lose all your time and money
  - with the data now morphed into an acceptable Shopify format, create the product in Shopify

Things that will drive you nuts include product options, and assigned images to variants. Good luck getting over the top on this one! Every single time I have attempted one of these jobs, I have been silly, estimated some low-ball effort like $5000 to get it done only to end up doubling my time and effort over the silliest little things.